# How to implement using statment (block) in powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell

How can I write a using block in PowerShell?

This is a working example in C#:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    Console.WriteLine("InUsing");
}
```

I need the same in PowerShell (not working):

```
Using-Object ($conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connString)) {
         
    Write-Warning -Message 'In Using';          
}
```

It is working without a using block:

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connString)
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: *not working* > What is the problem

Comment: you want to remove 'System.Data.SqlClient.'?

Comment: using statement make sures all the resource are released by calling Dispose of SqlConnection object.....So you can just call Dispose() folowed by Close() in powershell instead of Using

Comment: @Viru:I know that I can do Dispose()/Close() but I would like to using if possible. Not working means break

Comment: @Patrick Error is : The term 'Using-Object' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that 
the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/24576990/993547

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Here is a solution from [Using-Object: PowerShell version of C#’s “using” statement](https://davewyatt.wordpress.com/2014/04/11/using-object-powershell-version-of-cs-using-statement/) which works by calling `.Dispose()` in a finally block:

```cs
function Using-Object
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        [AllowEmptyCollection()]
        [AllowNull()]
        [Object]
        $InputObject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [scriptblock]
        $ScriptBlock
    )

    try
    {
        . $ScriptBlock
    }
    finally
    {
        if ($null -ne $InputObject -and $InputObject -is [System.IDisposable])
        {
            $InputObject.Dispose()
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how to use it:

```
Using-Object ($streamWriter = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter("$pwd\newfile.txt")) {
    $streamWriter.WriteLine('Line written inside Using block.')
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain me what you mean by $ErrorActionPreference ?

Comment: by default the $ErrorActionPreference is set to Continue, then in a try catch you will only trap crittical error's. (you actualy only trap errors that  stop the current flow)
you can override the error action with commandlets  if you you use -erroraction.  
but I made a mistake here, you don't use the catch block so you don't need to adjust the error action preference.
I 'll edit the answer!

Comment: I'd add a switch parameter to throw an exception if IDisposable isn't implemented (if not null). Otherwise, the program continues with the object not being released. I'd also add an output variable. As far as I can see, you won't be able to return anything.

Comment: You can simplify this a bit, the `-is` operator works just like in .NET. If you ask of a `null` value if it is of any type it will always return `false`. In other words, the `-is` operator does the `null` check as well.