# How To Prevent Invoke-SQLCMD from trimming Leading Zero's

Tags: powershell, leading-zero, invoke-sqlcmd

In powershell I have a script and every time it runs it needs to increment a number in a DB by one. Once it reaches 9999 it resets back to 0001. 
I have this functionality worked out in powershell my issue is that Invoke-SQLCMD
keeps stripping out any leading 0's

so If I want to update the DB value to `0001` it only updates it to `1`

Is there any way to have SQLCMD keep leading 0's?

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $dataSource -Database $database -Username $user -password $pass -Query "UPDATE DBO.TABLE_NAME SET sequence_no = $newFileNum"
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add how increment is done. Could be a integer/string converison issue, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Presumably, it is being stored in the DB as an integer, where it is standard practice to ignore leading zeros (because there'd be a lot of them).  If you want it to have the leading zeros for display later, you can format it yourself when you read it back.  For example: `"{0:0000}" -f 1`, which gives output: `0001`

Comment: `Invoke-SqlCmd` is entirely innocent. If `$newFileNum` contains a correct string (`0001`), you need to pass it as a string (`sequence_no = '$newFileNum'`). Otherwise, you'll send `sequence_no = 0001` to SQL Server, where SQL Server will just parse `0001` back into an `INT`. Or you can avoid both `Invoke-Sqlcmd` and string replacement altogether and use [proper parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50582924/41379160).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

invoke SQLCMD does this by default.
One way is when you run your query against SQL to get the value in there you can use `.ToString("0000")` to put the 0's back in or your can use this as your SQL query.