# How to safely update database using powershell syntax?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a PowerShell script which runs safely up to the point of an update. I connect to the database and can read from it, however, I have trouble updating.

Here is a copy of the error message I receive:
"Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."
At C:\xxx\xxx\ToolsController.ps1:37 char:5
+                 $InnerCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException"

FYI: I posted this before and this is an update to the previous question.
Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried attaching the variable at the end of the string i.e '..+$varibale'
also tried @" "@ and I have gotten the same result.

```
$Global:Server = "server"      
$Global:Database = "db"
$Global:u = "un"
$Global:p = "pw"
[string]$Query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[jobs] WHERE [Run] = 0"
try{
$ConnectionString = "server=$Server;Integrated Security=true;database=$Database;user id=$u;password=$p"
$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
$Connection.Open()
}
catch{
    "Failed to connect SQL Server"     
}

$Command = $Connection.CreateCommand()
$InnerCommand = $Connection.CreateCommand()
$Command.CommandText = $Query
$jobs = $Command.ExecuteReader()

    while ($jobs.Read()){

        switch($jobs["Script"]){                
            15
            {
                $traverse = $jobs["Frequency"] - 1
                While ($traverse -ge 0) {
                    c:\xx\xx\batch $jobs["Date"]
                    $traverse--
                }

                "Updating Database...."
                $Query2 = "UPDATE [dbo].jobs SET [Run] = 1 WHERE [ID] = $jobs['ID']" <------Error here.
                $InnerCommand.CommandText = $Query2
                $InnerCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                "Updating Completed!"
            }
        }
    }
$Connection.Close()
$Connection.Dispose()
Write-Host "Connection Closed"
```

Comment: Maybe just try simplifying by using Invoke-Sqlcmd and its parameters.

Comment: The message is clear: while you're reading from the `DataReader`, you cannot perform commands on the same connection. Read all the jobs into a collection first, then do a second loop where you perform the actual actions and update the jobs. Alternatively, you can open a second connection to do the `UPDATE` on, but this makes your processing far less efficient as you're holding the first connection open while you're doing something that could take a very long time (potentially longer than timeouts).

Comment: If I can toot my own horn for a moment, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50582924/4137916) has some code for conveniently reading objects from a `DataReader` (even more so than `Invoke-Sqlcmd`, which borrows all the weirdness of `sqlcmd`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` to the connection string. This will allow interleaving of `UPDATE` statements while reading from the data reader.