# How to use System.Threading.Monitor to lock an object/type in powershell?

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, powershell

I am using powershell to multithread a process that uses Invoke-SQLCMD to access a SQL Server database, each thread running its own background job. Knowing that Invoke-SQLCMD is not thread safe, I found ***[this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40091.automating-sql-operations-with-service-management-automation-sma-and-invoke-sqlcmd-challenges-and-solutions.aspx)*** article discussing how to make the function thread safe. He makes a wrapper for invoke-sqlcmd, locks on GUID before running the actual command, then releases the lock when it completes. Seems well and good to me!

However, in some testing I found that I clearly do not understand how to implement this in powershell. It seems straight forward in theory: lock on an object (in this case an arbitrarily chosen type) before doing a thing, and when you are done unlock it. In between locking and unlocking, anything that goes to lock that type should be denied. But that is not what I found to be true.

As I understood the locking function, this block of code should take ~10 seconds to run, but in reality takes only a couple seconds:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
 [System.Threading.Monitor]::Enter([guid])
 Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
 [System.Threading.Monitor]::Exit([guid])
}

[System.Threading.Monitor]::Enter([guid])
Write-Host 'GUID Unlocked'
[System.Threading.Monitor]::Exit([guid])
```

I also found that using [System.Threading.Monitor]::TryEnter([guid]) would always return true, even while the job that locked the type was running, and using [System.Threading.Monitor]::Wait([guid]) would cause the script to wait indefinitely, even past the 10 seconds that the background job should be locking the type for.

Is my issue that a lock inside of the job is not visible outside of the job? Or is it in my implementation of the lock? If anyone has suggestions on other ways to manage SQL connections in parallel, they would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Using all this hoopla to make `Invoke-Sqlcmd` "safe" seems a bit silly, compared to just writing a function that does what `Invoke-Sqlcmd` does but better. Certainly neither ADO.NET nor the database have a problem with parallel access (as long as you don't share objects, of course). Locking on a `Type` instance takes things from "silly" to "horrific". IMO, `Invoke-Sqlcmd` should not be used unless you have a need for the `sqlcmd` script behavior it imitates, otherwise just write standard ADO.NET code using `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlBulkCopy` for bulk copy operations.

Comment: If I can toot my own horn for a bit with regards to `Invoke-Sqlcmd` alternatives, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50582924/4137916) illustrates how to write a replacement for retrieving data with `Invoke-Sqlcmd` (and using actual, injection-safe parameters, which `Invoke-Sqlcmd` does not). There should be no problems with threading there, unless there's some subtle issue with connection pooling that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Consider your horn tooted, Jeroen. Thanks for the answer!