# Powershell datareader returns unwanted text

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I need some help, **the result string should be just "this is a test"** but it returns some other server information as well when I do a Write-Output:

```
$conStringCor = "Server=SERVER; Initial Catalog=master;"
$corCred = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential("user","pwd")

function GetScalarSQL($con_str, $cred, $cmd_text)
{  
    $result = [string]::Empty   
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($con_str, $cred)   
    try
    {
        $conn.Open()
        $tran = $conn.BeginTransaction()
        $cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
        $cmd.Transaction = $tran
        $cmd.CommandTimeout = 300
        $cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
        $cmd.CommandText = $cmd_text    
        $dr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()    
        if ($dr.Read())
        {
            $result = ($dr.GetValue(0))
        }
        $dr.Close()
        $dr.Dispose()
        $cmd.Dispose()
        $tran.Commit();
    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
        if($tran -ne $null){      
            $tran.Rollback();
        }
        throw $_.Exception
    }
    finally
    {
        $conn.Clone()
        $conn.Dispose()
    }

    return $result
}

try
{
    $updatesForDB = [string]::Empty
    $updatesForDB = GetScalarSQL $connString $corCred "select 'this is a test' as [test]"
    Write-Output $updatesForDB
        
}
catch [Exception]
{
    #Do something with the exception 
    Write-Output $_.Exception.ToString()
    #Write-Error "Job Failure" -EA Stop
    Write-Error $_.Exception.ToString() -EA Stop
}
```

The output of Write-Output $updatesForDB is:

StatisticsEnabled                : False
AccessToken                      :
ConnectionString                 : Server=XXXXX; Initial Catalog=master;
ConnectionTimeout                : 15
Database                         : master
DataSource                       : XXXXXXX
PacketSize                       : 8000
ClientConnectionId               : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
ServerVersion                    :
State                            : Closed
WorkstationId                    : XXXXXXX
Credential                       :
FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors : False
Site                             :
Container                        :

this is a test

thanks,

Comment: I would suggest piping any method that you are not capturing to `| Out-Null`. For example `$dr.Dispose() | Out-Null`

Comment: ohh I had $conn.Clone() in the function instead of $conn.Close() changing this fixed the issue, thanks!

Comment: Be careful with this approach if you ever need parameters, because there's a natural and almost unavoidable temptation to do this with string interpolation since that's so easy in PowerShell -- but that leads to all sorts of issues with SQL injection and escaping. If I can interest you in [stealing a bit of ready-made code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50582924/4137916)... Note that if you *do* need only a single value, `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` takes care of what you're now doing explicitly.

Comment: good point, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually as a common PowerShell problem.  PowerShell will write everything that is output from a function to the pipeline.  That's anything that is not consumed through an assignment or otherwise detoured away from the output stream.  That means anything that precedes your return statement, and thus more than what you've stored in `$Result`.

What you should do is figure out which method calls, or anything else are creating output and either pipe it to `Out-Null` or precede it with casting to `[Void]`.