# SQL Server : Can the Locale be set for datetime in INSERT statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I am using SQL Server 2014 database, and PowerShell 4.0

I am writing an application to restore records to a database. The database is complex, hence I am using Powershell to orchestrate the the csv-export, csv-import and merge.

I have a problem restoring datetime fields at the csv-import stage.

An original database Person record is:

```
Id  Name  Date                     A  B  C
11   Joe  2012-12-04 10:09:26.000  a  b  c
```

I export the record and the resultant contents of person.csv are:

```
"Id",  "Name",  "Date",                     "A",  "B",  "C"
"11",  "Joe",   "04/12/2012 10:09:26.000",  "a",  "b",  "c"
```

I create a temporary table call TempTable

```
CREATE TABLE TempTable (ID int,
            Name varchar(16),
            Date datetime,
            A varchar(10),
            B varchar(10),
            C varchar(10))
```

The import statement is:

```
import-csv("person.csv") | ForEach-Object {
                $Values = "'"+($_.Psobject.Properties.Value -join "','")+"'" }
```

The result:

```
$Values = '11','Joe','04/12/2012 10:09:26.000',  'a',  'b',  'c'
```

I then INSERT $Values into TempTable using

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "INSERT into TempTable VALUES ($Values)"
```

But the resultant data record is:

```
Id  Name  Date                     A  B  C
11   Joe  2012-04-12 10:09:26.000  a  b  c
```

The month and day have been interchanged. (Luckily I also used a date which has a day > 12, such as 2012-12-26, when I get a SQL conversion error since the datetime field is being passed a month=26. Otherwise I may not have spotted the problem until well downstream.)

I could break into the $Values String and manipulate the date to interchange the day and month, but this is clunky and for other tables there may be >1 date, and not necessarily in the same csv locations.

I could also extract the Date field from the $Values String and update separately using

```
"INSERT <all fields>"
"UPDATE TempTable SET Date = convert(datetime, $person.Date, 103) WHERE ID=$person.ID"
```

I checked the PowerShell datatypes, and the PowerShell Culture and they are correct. So I'm assuming the problem is that the sql INSERT statement is defaulting to a US locale where date is MM/dd/yyyy format. Is there an quick/elegant way of doing the insert and passing the desired format, or locale, at the same time?

Comment: Use [`SET DATEFORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) prior to the `INSERT` in the batch. However, you would be *far* better off using an unambiguous format (`yyyyMMdd` or `yyyyMMddThh:mm:ss`) or parametrising your statements with a date and time value.

Comment: The trick, really, is to not use ambiguous formats anywhere. See the links at [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates); specifically, the "Regional formats" section.

Comment: I second Aaron, in particular, do not rely on SQL Server's conversion logic for anything that's not 100%, always the same regardless of settings. As long as there is the option of performing a conversion client-side, even if it's slow or clunky, it still beats relying on the (arcane) T-SQL conversion rules. In this particular case, I heartily recommend *against* string interpolation, even if PowerShell makes this particularly tempting. Going the extra mile and parameterizing pays dividends. [Here's one we prepared earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50582924/4137916).

Comment: Thanks everyone. The SET DATEFORMAT does the trick, but I get the point about using unambiguous, specific formats.  I'm at the mercy of the PS's export-csv and import-csv cmdlets since they use the dd/MM/yyyy format, so 'something' has to be written to change the datetime before or after SQL INSERT.  But SET DATEFORMAT helps avoid code changes.

Comment: PowerShell is a complete programming language -- in particular, just because `Import-Csv` gives you strings doesn't mean you can't convert those values to `DateTime` objects before sending them off to SQL Server (and if they are `DateTime`, even if you do use string interpolation, you are in control of the format used for output). That shifts the conversion logic to the client side, which is a lot more predictable. Worst case you have to check the object types in a loop (if the properties aren't known in advance).

Comment: What mercy are you talking about? `Export-Csv` uses whatever the thread's current culture settings are. You can control the date/datetime/time formats by setting up the CultureInfo just like you would with .NET Framework/Core before invoking Export-Csv, e.g.: `[System.Globalization.CultureInfo] $newCulture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture.Clone()` `$newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd"` `$newCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFFK"` and `[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture =  $newCulture`