# PowerShell SQL Query to Update Table

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell to run a SQL query.  I then want to update another table based on information pulled from the query.  I have tested my SQL query and update statements directly in the SQL Server Management Studio so I know that they work.  The results of those tests show that there are over 800 records that should be updated.  However, when I run the same query and update from within PowerShell, it only updates one record.  I have mostly copied this script from another much larger script that was written in a similar format. But it appears that I am missing a ForEach loop (or something similar) but cannot figure out where to place it or how.   Here is my script:

```
# Set the database connection strings
    $Conn02 = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection "SERVER_INFORMATION"
    $mySQL02 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $mySQL02.Connection = $Conn02

    $Conn03 = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection "SERVER_INFORMATION"
    $mySQL03 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $mySQL03.Connection = $Conn03
    

#Connect to the database to perform the query
$Conn02.Open()

$mySQL02.CommandText = "SELECT IDNUM, FNAME, LNAME
        FROM TABLE1
        WHERE STATUS = 'C'"
        
 $SQL02 = $mySQL02.ExecuteReader()
 
       WHILE($SQL02.Read()){

        $NEWID = $SQL02['ID_NUM']
        $FNAME1 = $SQL02['FNAME']
        $LNAME1 = $SQL02['LNAME']
    }

#Run the update
$Conn03.Open()

    $mySQL03.CommandText = 
    
    "INSERT INTO TABLE2 (user_id,firstname,lastname)
     VALUES ('$NEWIDme','$FNAME1','$LNAME1')"
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: You perform only a single `INSERT`, so obviously you will only ever end up inserting a single row. The loop that reads the result just ends up discarding everything but the very last row. You should move the `INSERT` into the read loop (but still use a separate connection, since the reader is occupying the other one). Make sure to call `.Close()` on your connections when all is said and done (readers and commands technically need to be disposed as well, but closing the connection takes care of that).

Comment: Also, issuing commands through string interpolation opens you up to SQL injection, or at the very least errors when strings need escaping (last name `O'Toole` will not work correctly, for example, nor will `NULL` values). Use properly parameterized statements; it's a bit more work but it pays off. A [snippet for your perusal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50582924/4137916).

Answer (score 1):

As @jeroen said, you need to move the Insert statement into the while loop. Here is the code should look like:

```
#Connect to the database to perform the query
$Conn02.Open()

$mySQL02.CommandText = "SELECT IDNUM, FNAME, LNAME
        FROM TABLE1
        WHERE STATUS = 'C'"
        
 $SQL02 = $mySQL02.ExecuteReader()

 #Save reader into datatable
 $Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
 $Datatable.Load($SQL02) 

 #Close the connection
 $Conn02.Close()


 #Run the update
  $Conn03.Open()
  foreach($row in $dt){

        $NEWID = $row['ID_NUM']
        $FNAME1 = $row['FNAME']
        $LNAME1 = $row['LNAME']
  
        $mySQL03.CommandText =     
        "INSERT INTO TABLE2 (user_id,firstname,lastname)
        VALUES ('$NEWIDme','$FNAME1','$LNAME1')"

        $mySQL03.ExecuteNonQuery() 

    }
  $Conn03.Close()
```

To prevent SQL Injection I suggest using Parameters when assigning values

```
 foreach($row in $dt){

        $NEWID = $row['ID_NUM']
        $FNAME1 = $row['FNAME']
        $LNAME1 = $row['LNAME']
  
        $mySQL03.CommandText =     
        "INSERT INTO TABLE2 (user_id,firstname,lastname)
        VALUES (@NEWIDme,@FNAME1,@LNAME1)"
        
        $mySQL03.Parameters.Clear()
        $Command.Parameters.AddWithValue('@NEWIDme',$NEWID)  | Out-Null
        $Command.Parameters.AddWithValue('@FNAME1',$FNAME1)  | Out-Null
        $Command.Parameters.AddWithValue('@LNAME1',$LNAME1)  | Out-Null 
        $mySQL03.ExecuteNonQuery() 

    }
```