# Powershell | How to make an if statement that compares date from SQL Table with Date given in script

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, if-statement

**Background information:** So I am writing a Powershell script to clean up a SQL Server Database and I have a question on how to perform an if statement in this very specific case.

So the script works as follows:

- The Script connects to the SQL Server Database
- It get's the current date -5 days and converts it to unix Epoch time
- It takes that Epoch date and cuts off the decimals
- Then adds 3 zero's because the Database requires 13 numbers (Not sure why who ever set the database up decided to do this but it is what it is)
- Then comes the if statement **<-- my question**
- Define SQL Query
- Run the sql query

**The Question:** So I want to have an if statement that compares the converted unix epoch date with the epoch date from the SQL Server
Database Table and if the date is less or equal then the entries are deleted.

My code is currently as follows:

```
#### Variables ####
# Sorry for having to censor the variable inputs, wouldn't wanna leak this sensitive information everywhere.
$UID = 'uid'
$PASS = 'pass'
$SI = 'serverinstance'
$DB = 'database'
$Table = 'table'
$Table_age = 'date_column'
$Age = 5 # Maximum age of an entry
$DateDecimal = ',' # Depends on the PC but this might have to be changed to a .period instead
$EQLcompat = '000' # EQL Database compatibility for the Epoch time


#### Get date and convert to Epoch ####
$Date = Get-Date $((Get-Date).AddDays(-$Age).ToUniversalTime()) -UFormat +%s
#Substring the decimal values
$DateCut = $Date.Substring(0, $Date.IndexOf($DateDecimal)) 
#Make Epoch date EQL Database compatible
$unixTime = $DateCut + $EQLcompat


#### if statement in Question ####
if ($Table -le $unixTime){
  # SQL Query
  $SQLquery = "
  SELECT TOP (1) *
  FROM [$Table]
  "}

else{
    Write-Host 'Nope, not this way'  
  }


#### Run SQL Query ####
Invoke-Sqlcmd -serverinstance $SI -Database $DB -username $UID -password $PASS -query $SQLquery
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this if statement to make this work? Thank you very much!

EDIT 1:
I've tried `if (+ $Table -le $unixTime){` however this gives me the error code;

```
Cannot convert value "databasename" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At C:\Users\fabstefanm.GEMEENTENET\Documents\Code\SQL Table Cleaner.ps1:35 char:5
+ if (+ $Table -le $unixTime){
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger
```

EDIT 2:
Meant SQL Server not MySQL, my bad got the two names crossed.

EDIT 3:
I've changed the if statement to this:

```
#### if statement ####
if ($DB.output -le $unixTime){
  # SQL Query
  $SQLquery = "SELECT TOP (1) * FROM [$Table] WHERE [$Table_age] <= [$unixTime]"
  Write-Host 'Yes, this way'
  }
```

Now this does feel like I've come a step closer to solving the issue, however te error I now get is `Invoke-Sqlcmd : Invalid column name '1659532862000'.` So it does seem that I am not yet in the right place, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Don't compare strings to string when you want to compare integers to integers :) Assuming `$Table` contains a string representation of the timestamp (eg. `"1659951541000"`), the following should do the trick: `if(+$Table -le $unixTime)` - `+` will attempt conversion to a numerical type

Comment: This gives an error "Cannot convert value "databasename" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."" + if (+ $Table -le $unixTime){
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger

Comment: The `[ ]` is only relevant to escape identifiers, so `$unixTime` should not be surrounded by them. But better yet, it shouldn't be part of the query text at all -- as an integer this just about works, but passing strings, `NULL` values or things like `DATETIME`s is an exercise in suffering. `Invoke-Sqlcmd` sucks because it has no support for parameterization, so use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50582924/4137916) instead. (The table name and column name would still need to be interpolated, unless you want to get fancy with `sp_executesql`.)

Comment: I managed to make it work with some more fiddling around with the code. I posted it in the answer below if you're interested about how I made it work.

Comment: It's a bad idea storing unix timestamps in SQL Server in the first place. SQL Server is optimized around using DateTime columns. They are better for indexing, storage, and memory use, and have more support for date math. For example, if you had a DateTime column, you could build this entire thing in SQL and not need to substitute a parameter in the script at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed around the if statement slightly and now it all works. Of course it's just a select query and not yet the delete query, but that's not a big change.

This is the new if statement + SQLquery is this:

```
#### if statement ####
if ($DB.output -le $unixTime){
  # SQL Query
  $SQLquery = "SELECT TOP (10) [$Table_age] FROM [$DB].[dbo].[$Table] WHERE [$Table_age] >= $unixTime"

  Write-Host 'Yes, this way'
  }
```

So if anyone else ever comes across the need to use Powershell to run a task and then an SQL query with an if statement in it then I hope this can be of some assistance.