# Powershell insert date & time into SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell, sql-insert

Trying to insert data into SQL with PS. This is my code:

```
$date = Get-Date -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'

***Oracle Connection***

$Command.CommandText = "insert into Datetest VALUES ('$date')"
$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
$OracleConnection.Close()
```

The problem is, that the first column of the SQL Table requires data from type date and the following structure: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' but everytime I try to insert such data it gives me this error:

> "ORA-01830: Datumsformatstruktur
> endet vor Umwandlung der gesamten Eingabezeichenfolge
> "

En:

> "ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string"

When I just insert 'dd/mm/yyyy' it works, but it nulls the time...

This is the SQL:
[image]
[image]

Any ideas how to insert date & time into SQL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inserting a date into SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50582122/inserting-a-date-into-sql). Note that the linked question specifically uses `SqlConnection` (for SQL Server) and the cmdlets could be made more generic, but the general concept is the same for Oracle: use a parameterized statement with a typed parameter, not text interpolation.

Comment: Oracle's `DATE` type does not have a time component, you need to use a `TIMESTAMP` column if you want to store time too.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Jeroen @Mathias. I found a solution which works for php: 

`"insert into Datatest VALUES ( TO-DATE('".$date.", ".$time."', 'DD/MM/YYYY, HH24:MI'))"` 

But when trying to code it for PS: 
`"insert into Datetest VALUES (TO_DATE('".$date.", ".$time."', 'dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm:ff')"` 

It gives this error: "Die 'CommandText'-Eigenschaft 
wurde nicht festgelegt."

Comment: I have added the Oracle tag as this would appear to be for Oracle. Going by this doc https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-insert-and-retrieve-dates-in-oracle you should be using something in this format: `insert into Datetest (MyDateColumn) VALUES ('2022-10-24')`

Comment: Do not use SQL injection, use bind variables instead.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - that's not correct; Oracle's [DATE datatype](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-5405B652-C30E-4F4F-9D33-9A4CB2110F1B) does store the time, down to second precision.

Answer (score 0):

Going by these examples

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-insert-and-retrieve-dates-in-oracle

Try this

```
$date = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'



$Command.CommandText = "insert into Datetest VALUES (DATE '$date')"
$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
$OracleConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already managed to just insert the date into the sql table, but I need to insert both, date & time...