# Using Dapper in Powershell

Tags: powershell, dapper

I am trying to get Dapper to work in Powershell. I was not very successfull searching the internet for code samples, so I tried to roll my own ... and failed.

Here is what I did:

I am in C:\test and have an open powershell (in Windows Terminal that is). The following files are in C:\test\database:

```
Dapper.dll
Dapper.xml
database.db
database.sql
SQLite.Interop.dll
System.Data.SQLite.dll
System.Data.SQLite.dll.config
```

The SQLite DLLs come from https://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.117.0/sqlite-netFx46-binary-x64-2015-1.0.117.0.zip and were copied directly from the extracted archive to C:\test\database

The Dapper.dll and Dapper.xml were copied from a current Visual Studio 2017 C# Projects packages directory.

database.db contains a valid SQLite database that was created with the database.sql:

```
create table keypad (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    col1 VARCHAR(20),
    col2 VARCHAR(20),
    col3 VARCHAR(20)
);

insert into keypad values ( 1, "7", "8", "9" );
insert into keypad values ( 2, "4", "5", "6" );
insert into keypad values ( 3, "1", "2", "3" );
insert into keypad values ( 4, "0", "0", "," );
```

database.db can be queried with the following PS commands:

```
Add-Type -Path  "C:\test\database\System.Data.SQLite.dll"
$con = [System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection]::new("Data Source=C:\test\database\database.db")
$con.Open()
$cmd = [System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand]::new("select * from keypad", $con)
$rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
$rdr.HasRows
$rdr.FieldCount
$f=""; $fc = 0; 0..($rdr.FieldCount-1) | foreach { $f = "$f {$fc,5}"; $fc++ }
$f -f (0..($rdr.FieldCount-1) | foreach { $rdr.GetName($_) }); while ( $rdr.Read() ) { $f -f (0..($rdr.FieldCount-1) | foreach { $rdr.GetValue($_) }) }
```

Result is as expected:

```
    id  col1  col2  col3
     1     7     8     9
     2     4     5     6
     3     1     2     3
     4     0     0     ,
```

I would like to use Dapper for querying this table. I tried:

```
Add-Type -Path  "C:\test\database\System.Data.SQLite.dll"
Add-Type -Path  "C:\test\database\Dapper.dll"

$con = [System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection]::new("Data Source=C:\test\database\database.db")
$con.Open()
$sql = "select * from keypad where id = 1"
$res = $con.Query[dynamic]( $sql ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Everything above the last command does execute flawlessly, but the last command yields an ugly error message:

```
At line:1 char:19
+ $res = $con.Query[dynamic]( $sql ).FirstOrDefault();
+                   ~
Array index expression is missing or not valid.
At line:1 char:19
+ $res = $con.Query[dynamic]( $sql ).FirstOrDefault();
+                   ~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'dynamic]' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArrayIndexExpression
```

I am a bit puzzled how Dapper does do it's magic, since $con is essentially a System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection (at least Get-Member thinks of it this way), which does not know of a method by the name of Query.

How do I get Dapper to work in Powershell?

Comment: Basically, you don't. Dapper offers a bunch of extension methods on `DbConnection`. PowerShell doesn't support extension methods, nor does it support `dynamic` in any meaningful way, nor does it support constructing anonymous types (which Dapper relies on for parameters). While you *can* invoke the extension methods as regular static methods, and just use `object` for the type, and pass parameters manually, at that point you're hardly better off just writing your own cmdlets ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50582924/4137916)), especially since you don't have to bother with packages.

Comment: fair enough - I probably do not understand much of what you are talking about concerning the .NET details. But I get the idea. Maybe I have a long way to go to grasp all of it. So I will look for a feasibly workaround. Thanks for the pointers you have given!