# PowerShell get file MD5 as base64 string

Tags: .net, powershell

I have the following .NET code that generates a base64 string of a file MD5:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream) fileStream, (ICryptoTransform) md5, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            do
              ;
            while (cryptoStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(md5.Hash);
        }
    }
}
```

It's part of a working code.

Now I need to create a PowerShell script that does some automation and also needs to create the same base64 hash of the file. I have written the following:

```
$uploadFilePath = "C:\temp\test.txt"
$fileHashMD5 = Get-FileHash $uploadFilePath -Algorithm MD5
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($fileHashMD5.Hash)
$fileHashBase64 =[Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
```

But this returns a result that is different from the one generated above.

What am I doing wrong in my PS script?

Comment: You're using 7-bit US-ASCII to convert a hex string to bytes that don't match that hex string at all

Comment: BTW the .NET code is quirky too. You could use [ComputeHash(Stream)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.computehash?view=netcore-3.1#System_Security_Cryptography_HashAlgorithm_ComputeHash_System_IO_Stream_) with a stream, no need to read the data in a loop. You could just write `var bytes=md5.ComputeHash(fileStream);`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Tried it - still gives different result

Comment: Tried what? What did you try, what did you get? The code in the question is *definitely* wrong. `Get-FileHash` isn't broken. `still gives different result` would mean that the hex strings are different. Are they? If not, it's the code that converts one string format to another that needs fixing

Comment: Why don't you use the hex string as-is? Git hashes are hex strings, not Base64

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need to communicate with a specific service that verifies this hash and computes it as the .NET code shows - not something I can change and therefor I need to adjust myself to it's rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up writing the following function that mimics what the .NET functions does:

```
function Calc-File-Hash($filename) {
    $filename = resolve-path $filename
    Using-Object($fileStream = new-object System.IO.FileStream($filename, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)) {
        Using-Object($md5 = [System.Security.Cryptography.MD5]::Create()) {
            $cryptoStream = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream($fileStream, $md5, [System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode]::Read)
            $buffer = [System.Byte[]]::new(4096)
            do {
    
            }
            while ($cryptoStream.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length) -gt 0)
            return [Convert]::ToBase64String($md5.Hash)
        }
    }
}
```

`Using-Object` function taken from the following post:
[How to implement using statement in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107851/how-to-implement-using-statement-in-powershell)

Comment: You already had the hash with just `Get-FileHash $uploadFilePath -Algorithm MD5`. The problem was the rest of the code - the hash is a hex representation of the bytes. Getting the 7-bit US-ASCII representation of that string returns completely different bytes

Answer (score 1):

Is it a difference between upper and lower case of the MD5 string? Take this example:

```
> [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("string to encode".ToLower()))
> c3RyaW5nIHRvIGVuY29kZQ==
> [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("string to encode".ToUpper()))
> U1RSSU5HIFRPIEVOQ09ERQ==
```

The same string but different base64 outputs.

Comment: That's the same bug the question's code shows - the hash is a hex string. You can't get the value of a hex string by using encodings