# PowerShell System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection shows no error but also no result

Tags: sql-server, powershell

This script runs without any problems for a SQL Server connection:

```
[string] $connectionString = "Server=$server;Database=$database;Integrated Security = False; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"

$sqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConn.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$sqlConn.Open()
Write-Host "The connection is $($sqlConn.State)"
$command = $sqlConn.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query
$result = $command.ExecuteReader()
$sqlConn.Close();
Write-Host "The connection is $($sqlConn.State)"

$table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
$table.Load($result)
```

But only with that result

```
The connection is Open
The connection is Closed
```

I have tried many proper SQL queries which run in Management Studio without any problems. Any hint how to properly execute and maybe check the SQL connection?

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: By the way, you should dispose your connection and reader, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107851/how-to-implement-using-statement-in-powershell

Comment: thanks for your replies. Thought it's all covered in the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$result` variable is a `SqlDataReader`. You need to leave the connection open when loading the data table from the reader:

```
$sqlConn.Open()
Write-Host "The connection is $($sqlConn.State)"

$command = $sqlConn.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query
$table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
$result = $command.ExecuteReader()
$table.Load($result)

$sqlConn.Close();
Write-Host "The connection is $($sqlConn.State)"
```

Consider simplifying using a `SqlDataAdapter`:

```
$dataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($query, $connectionString)
$table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
$dataAdapter.Fill($table)
```