# Creating a user and login or connect new user to existing sql server login with azure cli command?

Tags: authentication, azure-sql-database, azure-cli

I was just wondering if there is a way to create a user and either creating or connect that user to an existing azure sql server login using azure cli?

**EDIT:**

I would do it with something like this in sql, for example:

```
-- For login login_name, create a user in the database
CREATE USER <username> FOR LOGIN <login> WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo]
GO

-- Add user to the database owner role
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'<username>'
GO
```

Comment: Firstly, I have logged in to azure using `az login`

![Image1](https://i.imgur.com/PdhOHio.png)

Then i have set the Subscription using :

     **az account set --subscription "Azure Sub name"**

Comment: Then i have executed the command to create user:

     **az sql server ad-admin create --resource-group "Rg name" --server "servername" --display-name "user1" --object-id "a209933ef"**

Here object is the object id of user in Azure Active directory.
Output:
![image2](https://i.imgur.com/kMz9Fzb.png)

Comment: Then in Portal:

![image3](https://i.imgur.com/zYreHdh.png)

Comment: @RithwikBojja I'll have to check it out though i'll have to follow up on that last question as i have to wait for my PR to be cleared to test this out.

Would be good if you could combine all the answers to a single answer post so i can mark it as the answer if all works well :)

Thanks so much for answering though! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use below command to run sql query in Azure PowerShell and I followed [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66368785/powershell-system-data-sqlclient-sqlconnection-shows-no-error-but-also-no-result):**

```
    $servername = "sqlservername.database.windows.net"
    $databasename = "databasename"
    $username = "rithwik"
    $pass = "R!th"
    $query = "CREATE USER User2 For login xxx WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo]"
    $sqlCon = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $sqlCon.ConnectionString = "Server=$servername;Database=$databasename;User ID=$username;Password=$pass;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
    $sqlCon.Open()
    $sqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $sqlCon)
    $sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
    $sqlCon.Close()
```

**Here xxx is the login name.**

[image]

**Then the user is created:**

[image]

Then you use
`$query = "EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_or', N'<username>'"` in place of above $query to add role.

Comment: Very interesting. I'll mark this as the answer if it works with the deploy later. :)
Thanks again @RithwikBojja :)

Comment: So i tested this and it worked! :) Though i could't implement it on our current project as we don't permit the service accounts with the needed rights. But testing it as a POC worked fine. :)