# Send mail using powershell keeps attachment locked even Dispose

Tags: powershell

I'm using a simple PS script. I need to send an email with every txt file in a folder as attachment, and if it's ok move this file. First part it work fine, the problem is when I try to move the file, is always locked. I read in many posts about $smtp.dispose() and $attachment.dispose() but it doesn't work for me. I always get this error message:

```
Move-Item : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
At C:\in\mail.ps1:41 char:5
+     Move-Item -Path $file -Destination C:\in\hist -force
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\in\CL..._0000345053.txt:FileInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveFileInfoItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

This is the script

```
#Connection Details
$username=””
$password=””
$smtpServer = “10.10.10.10”
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage

#Change port number for SSL to 587
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25) 

#Uncomment Next line for SSL  
#$smtp.EnableSsl = $true

$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( $username, $password )

#From Address
$msg.From = "src@dom.com"
#To Address, Copy the below line for multiple recipients
$msg.To.Add(“dest@dom.com”)

#Message Body
$msg.Body=””

#Message Subject
$msg.Subject = “File”


#your file location
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\in\*.txt"
$dest = "C:\in\hist"

Foreach($file in $files)
{
    Write-Host "Attaching File :- " $file
    $attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment –ArgumentList $file.FullName
    $msg.Attachments.Add($attachment)
    $smtp.Send($msg)
    $attachment.Dispose()
    $msg.Dispose()
    $smtp.Dispose()
    
    Move-Item -Path $file -Destination $dest -force
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the built-in cmdlet Send-MailMessage?

Comment: Actually disposing in powershell does not always work as intended. What you can try is making the sending mail script as separate script and invoke it in another scope.  Other way is to implement something like C#'s `using` https://stackoverflow.com/a/42108420/5720797

Comment: Why not move the files **after** the foreach loop? Add a pause there and then move them all with `Move-Item -Path $files.FullName -Destination $dest -Force`

Answer (score 0):

The attachment has not been released. Add `$attachment.Dispose()` to the foreach, it should release the file.