# ensuring that all invoke-sqlcmd commands happen within the same transaction?

Tags: .net, sql-server, powershell

**How do we ensure that the following function is executed within 1 database transaction?**

```
#
# Get SQL Files recursively
#
function GetFiles($path = $pwd) 
{ 
    $subFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory  | Select-Object FullName,Name | Sort-Object -Property Name 
    $sqlFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.sql | Select-Object FullName,Name | Sort-Object -Property Name
    
    foreach ($file in $sqlFiles)
    {
      Write-Host "file: " $file.Name
      Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $DBName -Username $SvcAdminAccount -Password $SvcAdminPassword -InputFile $file.FullName -QueryTimeout 65535 -ea stop
    } 

    foreach ($folder in $subFolders)
    {
       Write-Host "`nGetting files for subfolder: " $folder.Name
       GetFiles $folder.FullName
    } 
}
```

This function iterates through a directory and will invoke-sqlcmd for every file. **How do we ensure that the entire function is executed in one sql transaction>?**

Comment: You'll need to create one large batch to pass via `invoke-sqlcmd`. You'll likely be better off using your `ForEach` to create a SQL file and have to ensure you enable `XACT_ABORT` at the start of the batch and a declared tranasction, so that if any of the statements fail, everything is rolled back.

Comment: Each `Invoke-Sqlcmd` is a separate session with the database. Transactions cannot span sessions. As @Larnu suggested, create one .sql script with appropriately placed `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` and `END TRANSACTION;` statements if you are on SQL Server.

Comment: Or you can use `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection`, where you can do `BeginTransaction`

Answer (score 1):

**We can utilize the standard ADO.Net classes `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`**

It's best to dispose these in `try/finally` blocks, for which I have used `Using-Object` function [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42108420/14868997)

```
$sqlFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.sql | Select-Object FullName,Name | Sort-Object -Property Name;

$connString = "Server=YourServer;Database=$DBName;User Id=$SvcAdminAccount;Password=$SvcAdminPassword";

Using-Object ($conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connString) {
    $conn.Open();
    
    Using-Object ($tran = $conn.BeginTransaction()) {
        foreach ($file in $sqlFiles)
        {
          Write-Host "file: " $file.Name
          $comm = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $file,$conn,$tran;
          $comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        $tran.Commit();
    };
};
```

```
function Using-Object
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        [AllowEmptyCollection()]
        [AllowNull()]
        [Object]
        $InputObject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [scriptblock]
        $ScriptBlock
    )

    try
    {
        . $ScriptBlock
    }
    finally
    {
        if ($null -ne $InputObject -and $InputObject -is [System.IDisposable])
        {
            $InputObject.Dispose()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "SqlCommand" and the argument count: "3".

Comment: Sorry should be fixed now