# Powershell SQLite not releasing database file

Tags: powershell, sqlite, file-move

Im trying to move file after reading database file but im getting error that it is being used by another process.

My code

```
$sDatabasePath=testfile.dat
$sDatabaseConnectionString=[string]::Format("data source={0}",$sDatabasePath)
$oSQLiteDBConnection = New-Object System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection
$oSQLiteDBConnection.ConnectionString = $sDatabaseConnectionString
$oSQLiteDBConnection.open()

$oSQLiteDBCommand=$oSQLiteDBConnection.CreateCommand()
$oSQLiteDBCommand.Commandtext="SELECT * from table_id"
$oSQLiteDBCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
$oDBReader=$oSQLiteDBCommand.ExecuteReader()



while($oDBReader.HasRows) 
{
    if($oDBReader.Read())
    {
     $resultName = $oDBReader["name"]
    }
}




$oSQLiteDBConnection.close()


Move-Item -Path testfile.dat -Destination /somepath/
```

I found that it helped for others to add system gc collect but no luck for my code and still throws same error.
I just need to close DB connection with releasing file and move file to another location

Comment: Put connection into a using block so resources are disposed after exiting block.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107851/how-to-implement-using-statement-in-powershell?force_isolation=true

Comment: Make sure to call the `.Dispose()` method for _all_ .NET objects: `$oSQLiteDBCommand, $oDBReader, $oSQLiteDBConnection | ForEach-Object Dispose`