# Azure Runbook: using Set-CsUserCallingSettings throws "The stream was already consumed. It cannot be read again"

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-teams, azure-runbook

I am trying to use Azure RunBook with PowerShell to manage the call forwarding status for Teams users. I use an Azure app that has (I believe) all required Graph API permissions:

[image: Graph API permissions]

And is also set as Teams Administrator.

**Important note: I'm running it in 5.1 version, the 7.1 preview kept saying that I have incorrect access rights, which was a bull**

The Runbook PowerShell code is as follow:

```
#Import Modules
Import-Module MSAL.PS 
Import-Module MicrosoftTeams  

#Clear Tokencache
Clear-MsalTokenCache 

#Variables
$TenantId = "TenantID of my app"
$ClientID = "ClientId  of my app" #DemoTeamsPS app
$ClientSecret ="generated secret"


$graphtokenBody = @{   
   Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"   
   Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"   
   Client_Id     = $ClientID
   Client_Secret = $ClientSecret   
}  

$graphToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 
"https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body 
$graphtokenBody | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access_Token 

$teamstokenBody = @{   
   Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"   
   Scope         = "48ac35b8-9aa8-4d74-927d-1f4a14a0b239/.default"   
   Client_Id     = $ClientID 
   Client_Secret = $ClientSecret 
} 

$teamsToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $teamstokenBody | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access_Token 

Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccessTokens @("$graphToken", "$teamsToken")  

Get-CsOnlineUser -Identity me@myOrganisation.com | fl *Ent*,*host*,*voice*, *um*
```

Up to this line, everything works fine, the test pane returns my details. However, I am trying to change the call forwarding rules. Hence the two lines:

```
Set-CsUserCallingSettings -Identity me@myOrganisation.com  -IsUnansweredEnabled $FALSE
Set-CsUserCallingSettings -Identity me@myOrganisation.com  -IsForwardingEnabled $true -ForwardingType Immediate -ForwardingTargetType SingleTarget -ForwardingTarget "+1234567891"
```

But this returns an error "The stream was already consumed. It cannot be read again" (twice actually, one for each line).

Do you have any ideas?

Note: using

```
 Get-CsUserCallingSettings -Identity me@mycompany.com
```

returns the same error

EDIT: I had to abandon this approach, as Azure Runebook doesn't support  GET/SET-CsUserCallingSettings

Comment: In c# the solution is to put the code in a using block so the object gets disposed.  So you close the first connection before attempting the second.  Here is the PS solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107851/how-to-implement-using-statement-in-powershell

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, but I don't think that is the issue, after using "Connect-MicrosoftTeams" I am connected until either some hidden timeout or disconnect command, so I should be definitely still connected when the "Set-CsUserCallingSetting" is modified.

Comment: The title says "The stream was already consumed".  You code is trying to use the stream a second time.  A HTTP Request/Response must close and open a new connection for each transition.  So you must make sure the connection is disposed before and second attempt is done.

Comment: @jdweng OK... **how would I do that?** There is a "CONNECT" command and I can put the SET-CSUserCallSettings straight after with similar results, whie I can put many other commands like GET-CSOnlineUser.

Comment: Simple way is to have a variable $running (true/false) and put before and after the call to azure.  Then display message if user runs one command before another finishes.  Connect to can set to $null at beginning of code and then test if it is not $null before trying a connection so you do not get two connection using same stream.

Comment: The OP notes that they have all expected permissions however, the only information I located come from the German language [Microsoft Teams / Teams for companies Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/de-de/msteams/forum/all/powershell-microsoftteams-error-get/8ce1d617-f5dc-4cb9-8263-beebfebd79dc). Which lists at least the role of `Teams Communications Support Engineer` is required.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake It seems that  Get-CsUserCallingSettings is not supported on Azure runebook.

Comment: @Yasskier ah, admittedly I did miss that in the OP.  This was, however, the place my search for the listed exception, when calling against the Teams endpoint continually lead. Hopefully for others beyond my own [future self](https://m.xkcd.com/979/)... ;-)