# SSIS Catalog and Project Deployment with PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, powershell, ssis

I'm trying to create a ssis catalog with power-shell

i'm getting a weird error. this is the code i'm running: 
i took the code from [msdn](http://SSIS%20Catalog%20and%20Project%20Deployment%20with%20PowerShell)

```
 $SQLserver = "BM-ELAD\DRC_BUG_RESTORE"
$Link      = "false"
$pass      = "123456"
# Load the IntegrationServices Assembly
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices")

# Store the IntegrationServices Assembly namespace to avoid typing it every time
$ISNamespace = "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices"

# Create a connection to the server
$sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=$SQLserver;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $sqlConnectionString

# Create the Integration Services object
$integrationServices = New-Object $ISNamespace".IntegrationServices" $sqlConnection

# Provision a new SSIS Catalog

    $catalog = New-Object $ISNamespace".Catalog" ($integrationServices, "SSISDB", "$pass") 
    $catalog.Create()
```

and this is the error i'm getting:

```
GAC    Version        Location                                                                                                                                                                
---    -------        --------                                                                                                                                                                
True   v2.0.50727     C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices\13.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.dll       
New-Object : The term 'New-Object' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:13 char:18
+ $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $sqlConnectionSt ...
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-Object:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Has anyone ever encountered this problem? am i missing a file?

i tried this fix: [failed fix](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1a368511-0e9c-4867-ba97-ab07c777fe89/missing-microsoftsqlservermanagementintegrationservicesdll?forum=sqlintegrationservices) and it didn't work.
my powershell version is 4.0

when i do this manually, it works.

Comment: I've used the exact same example with no issue (also PS v4). Have you tried quitting PowerShell/ISE and reopening? This SO link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576990/ - mentions a corrupt PS install.

Comment: my PowerShell was corrupt, don't know how i missed that :\ thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to help, @Elad L. I would think that a corrupt PowerShell install isn't a common occurence.